# PHP preg_replace with capture group

Tags: php, preg-replace

How can I use `preg_replace` with a capture group as so?:

```
preg_replace('/testing\[([0-9]+)\]/', $this->storeNew[**THE NUMBER THAT WAS IN BETWEEN**], $this->code);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) with a custom function to achieve that.

You could do it for example this way:

```
class A {

    private $code = 'testing[82]';

    public function match() {
            return preg_replace_callback('/testing\[([0-9]+)\]/',function($matches) {

         return $this->storeNew($matches[1]);

    }, $this->code);

    }

    private function storeNew($number){
        return ++$number;
    }

}  

$a = new A();
echo $a->match();
```

It gets a bit tricky with $this, so you might need something like (below  @NiettheDarkAbsol code):

```
$src = $this->storeNew;
preg_replace('/testing\[([0-9]+)\]/', function($n) use ($src) {
    return isset($src[$n[1]]) ? $src[$n[1]] : $n[0];
    // return unchanged if not found in array
},$this->code);
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I couldn't write code at that moment. I updated also with my code.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to post "incomplete" answers with intent to edit later...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've wanted to edit it just in a minute but kids didn't know about my plans :)

Comment: You could've said "stand by for codez!" or something XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol True, I'll remember about it next time

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure in which way you would like to make use of the number. If you are just in need of the number itself and nothing else I wouldn't make use of a RegEx, instead use:

```
filter_var('testing[83]', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```